# How can I repel or trap lizards?

Tags: pest-control

I know a lizard was hiding in a certain place and unable to get rid of it.

I kept garlic, onion and naphthalene balls as some suggested but no use.

Either i would need to know a use and throw way to catch the lizard or need to place something to avoid it.

Pls help me with suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the lizard doing to bother you?

Comment: Sprayed solutions of hot sauce are widely recommended for lizard problems, but capsaicin, the hot stuff, irritates mostly mammals, not birds or reptiles or insects. *look elsewhere*.

Comment: glue stick boards resolves the problem as i know the places where lizards will go

Comment: Do you  prefer the bugs that the lizard is eating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is a small live animal trap. Havahart is the most common brand and is widely available in hardware stores with an agricultural bent.

If it's a salamander rather than an actual lizard you may need to cover the trap so it's dark and inviting enough. That's an educated guess; I'm not an herpetologist.

Comment: Can u say some easy tip available in india?

Comment: Easy....If we known the place...Easy..Just 2$ glue stick board - https://www.amazon.in/Cockroach-Insects-Rodents-Adhesive-Children/dp/B074DZ7RP2